# Making sweet vermouth

Tags: liqueur, recipes

Does anyone have a recipe for making a sweet vermouth with orange and caramel?

I have looked around but there doesn’t seem to be that many recipes available on the WWW.

If anyone can recommend which herbs to use that would also be great.

Comment: Google with the phrase “adding herbs to sweet vermouth” yields plenty of hits.

Comment: For instance this recipe has orange and lots of other herb and spices. http://www.vikredistillery.com/blog/2016/9/23/bpypj6a4vby7s8yzpwz8sgqckgn5kl

Comment: And this one too: https://www.theguardian.com/food/2018/dec/29/homemade-sweet-vermouth-from-leftover-wine-waste-not

Comment: And this one has caramel too. https://twobittart.com/2018/12/12/homemade-vermouth/